# Are there specific microwave antennas for digital and analog signal transmission?

Tags: antenna, microwave

I'm supposed to do a class report on microware antennas. The report said we have to present 1 microwave antenna that sends digital signal and another that sends analog signals.

Do you know such specific antenna ? (I'll then work on googling their technical specifications)

Comment: Then either the report is incorrect in its assumptions about the nature of things or you are misrepresenting said report.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm starting to realize it with the answer below. Anyways this is what I heard in class (knowing my teacher I'm not even surprise about you guys reactions)

Comment: It may be talking about bands that are dedicated to data transmissions versus (different) bands that are dedicated to linear (or analogue) transmissions.

Comment: @Andyaka Please see the update on my OP

Comment: @JasonKrs not really fond of your update. It completely changes the question to a different question. I'd recommend posting your new question as separate question and reverting the update here.

Comment: Sadly it's not unusual to have teachers that don't themselves really understand the material, and therefore ask nonsensical questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There's no physical difference between digital signals and analog signals on the air. Both are converted to analog voltages.

The only things about the electrical system that attaches to the antenna that matter for an antenna are

- center frequency
- bandwidth
- impedance

Selling an antenna "for digital transmissions" is like selling a car to "transport green apples". The color of apples doesn't have anything to do with their transportability. The question whether the data that is modulated onto a microwave signal is analog or digital has nothing to do with their bandwidth, center frequency or the device's impedance.

Comment: okay. But are there antennas (or their associated control boxes) that can only perform digital or analog ''tasks''  or both (though on the air it's all analog) ?

Comment: Antenna directivity and gain also matter in most cases.

Comment: @Andyaka Nontheless I saw a technical specification paper distinctly identifying an antenna as one for digital ''transmission'' http://www.hypcom.fr/doc/Doc%20Link%20F%20H%200906_FR.pdf  It's in french (I think numerique == digital   && faisceau hertzien == microwave)

Comment: @JasonKrs that doesn't actually mean anything – it just meant to say "this works well for usage with digital systems". Simply because almost all microwave links are digital these days. It's marketing speech. You can buy "WiFi antennas" at every electronics store. They are not specifically for WiFi – they just work well at the frequencies that wifi runs at (and can be just as well used for any other system at the same frequencies); if you ask a question and get an answer…

Comment: Ahhh ok then. But their counterparts arent easy to find on the net (for a beginner like me). So, do you know any antenna for ''this works well for usage with analog systems'' ?

Comment: what did I just explain? **there is no such thing as a digital or analog antenna**

Comment: There's three bullet points in my answer. Write down these three for the signal you want to transmit or receive, and find an antenna that fulfills these three criteria.

Comment: selling an antenna "for digital transmissions" is like selling a car to "transport green apples". The color of apples doesn't have anything to do with their transportability. The question whether the data that is modulated onto a microwave signal is analog or digital has nothing to do with their bandwidth, center frequency or the device's impedance.

Comment: I think I get it now....The antenna must fullfill the ''control box '' capacity (or specification if you will). Those two ''control box'' below are specifically designed for digital / analog. http://www.broadcast-eletec.com/equipement-fm/liaison-faisceau/faisceau-hertzien-television-analogique/    http://www.broadcast-eletec.com/equipement-tv/faisceau-hertzien-digital/faisceau-hertzien-numerique-television/   Correct me if I'm  wrong again

Comment: @Jason Krs Look, what you're asking is very "slippery" and you need to provide more background about your class and the report itself.  As Marcus already mentioned numerous times, there are no analog or digital antennas, but there are antenna systems that might be more suitable for expectations of an analog system or of a digital system.  For example, there are TV standards that allow use multiple transmitter antennas (for example Alamouti scheme and DVB-T2). So if you're buying an DVB-T2 antenna **system**, it could consist of two antennas.

Comment: @Jason Krs There are also WiFi antenna systems that have multiple antennas for spatial diversity or spatial multiplexing. Spatial multiplexing is commonly thought of as a digital technique, so you, if you're stretching things a bit in the marketing sense or selling antennas to the uninitiated, could call such antennas "digital", even though they're analog.

Comment: @Jason Krs Also, you don't have your profile filled out, so once again, I have to ask for more information about the class. Some introductory classes might use the principle of [lie to children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) to bring some points across. Depending on the teacher, a correct answer might or might not bring full amount of points. If it's the second case, you're in the difficult situation where you need to figure out what the teacher expects.

Comment: @AndrejaKo please see the update on my OP

Comment: @JasonKrs Perhaps there is a misunderstanding of where a "control-box" ends and an antenna begins. To an engineer, the control-box term is not meaningful. The power flow is *into* the antenna from a signal source. The signal source is never  well-described as "digital".

Answer (score 2):

Your "control boxes" are Modems (short for MODulator/DEModulator).

Of course, these boxes need to be aware of what kind of transmission they do. You can transmit any sufficiently band-limited signal over an RF link.

So these boxes might just be transmitting garage door opener codes, they might be transmitting analog audio that is analogly modulated as FM, they might transmit the same audio modulated as analog AM, but they might also transmit that same audio using a digital audio transmission standard.

Realistically, microwave communication links of the last 30 years can be expected to be digital, since you usually want to transmit *data* that is already in digital form, anyway.

Comment: @JasonKrs I'm sorry, but please don't do such things. It's bad style. Ask a separate question that everyone sees.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an application from 1950's - maybe a radar or telephone multichannel link, definitely analog. Then a digital application of today, maybe a desktop WiFi-box or a car door remote controller opened to show the microstrip antenna.

You should notice and say that the radiowave is the same - so is the antenna, only signals have different modulations. That is well told in the comments and other answers.