# Are there specific "control boxes" for digital and analog transmission used my microwave antennas?

Tags: antenna, control-system, microwave

Following of [Are there specific microwave antennas for digital and analog signal transmission?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281930/are-there-specific-microwave-antennas-for-digital-and-analog-signal-transmission?noredirect=1#comment642029_281930), I think I understand that Antennas A and B are neither analog nor digital. On the "control boxes" modulate the signals in analog or digitals

I'm taking a telecommunication class and the current topic is about interconnecting remote locations. I'm trying to identify distinct equipment (which I call control boxes) that are used for digital or analog transmission with microwave antennas.

Below is an image (sorry for the heavy copy/pase) of the architecture we are dealing with right now in the class.

[image]

Then my (more accurate) question would be are there specific control boxes for analog or digital (or both) transmission ? (btw what is the technical term for "control boxes"

Comment: If this is a class, why not ask the teacher ?

Comment: Who are "they"?

Comment: @FakeMoustache  Hmm..... Please read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281930/are-there-specific-microwave-antennas-for-digital-and-analog-signal-transmission?noredirect=1#comment642029_281930

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Typo mistake ..."There"

Comment: A bit of googling around digital modulation and analog(ue) modulation techniques would prove edifying.

Comment: @JasonKrs if you need to write a report then just copy and paste all the really good advice you are being given and submit that because either the lecturer is a moron or you are not correctly translating what you have been asked to do. Don't submit this comment just in case the lecturer is an actual moron.

Comment: If it helps, try to think of "Digital" as anything needing or using *digital* logic and "Analog" as everything else. When you're working with the black art that is microwave circuit design, "digital" is just a fancy word for "really fast analog"

Answer (score 0):

Stop and actually *think* about this.

Your "control boxes" are apparently doing modulation at the transmitter and de-modulation at the receiver.  How do you imagine a de-modulator for one type of modulation will work when presented with a carrier modulated differently?

Note that there are many many different modulation schemes that use different amounts of bandwidth for the same carried signal, have different levels of signal to noise ratio, have different characteristics with other signals using the same frequency range, etc.

The real question is how you can even imagine that a receiver that performs a specific type of de-modulation would ever work with a signal modulated differently.

Comment: so the receiver can do both analog and digital conversion ?

Comment: *analog and digital conversion* The fact that you ask this for me means that you do not understand *how* these microwave link systems work. There is no such thing as *analog and digital conversion*, there's analog to digital and digital to analog. So what do you mean ? And how would that be relevant, why would that be needed ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache First I thought there was distinct Antennas for analog and digital transmission (now I know there are not from a prior question)... But I was asked to make a report on analog vs digital microwave "antennas" thats why I camehere to ask questions

Comment: Then you cannot make a report because all antennas are **analog**. Even when used for distributing information in digital form, the antenna is still analog. What you could write a report about is **microwave systems for digital and analog applications**. But since transporting analog signals is inefficient, it is an obsolete way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want consider the control boxes and everything between them as a single system for sending either analog or digital data then the microwaves part of the question is irrelevant.

You are asking is an analog transmission system different from a digital one.

Think about what would happen if you used the wrong one.

Can you pass a digital signal through an analog system?

Since the real world is inherently analog (ignoring quantum effects) then clearly you can. Wires are analog and digital signals pass down them just fine.
However digital signals normally change far quicker than analog ones so the issue becomes whether the analog system has sufficient bandwidth to cope with the signal. If it does then it will work, if it doesn't then the signal will be distorted and the output won't be a true representation of the input.

Can you pass an analog signal through a digital system?

If I have to explain why the answer to this is no then you need to go and read the definitions of analog and digital again.

Why not make all the boxes analog and be done with it?

Efficiency. A digital system can use various encoding techniques that allow a far higher data rate with lower error rate than you could ever get sending digital data over an analog channel.

I have no evidence to support this but I suspect that any modern analog microwave transmission system is probably a digital system with an ADC on the input and a DAC on the output. It would give a greater sensitivity and error resistance than a pure analog system and probably cost less to build.

Comment: Hard evidence might be scarce, but I'd like to see someone implement 4G in an all analog system, I say good luck to them...